# django: regroup on inheritance child field

Tags: python, django

In a Django template, I try to regroup a list on a field which belong to a sub-model ([multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)).

my model.py

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # ...

class Shopping_place(Place):
    shopping_cat = models.ForeignKey(Shopping_Cat)
    # ...
```

my template.html

```
{% regroup place_list.shopping_place.all by shopping_cat as shopping_cat_list %}
```

my view.py

```
place_list = Place.objects.all()
```

And I'd like to avoid sending a `Shopping_place` (the sub-model) to my template...

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Is the regroup not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `place_list` is an interable of `Place` instances (probably a queryset) you're calling `shopping_place` on the wrong object - you're asking the whole iterable for a shopping place, not the individual instances.  If you're sure all your places are shopping places, try:

```
{% regroup place_list by shopping_place.shopping_cat as shopping_cat_list %}
```